# .htaccess - 301 redirect move all pages to https:// - except 1 page?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have the following code that redirects any http:// request to https:// - This work great, but how would I edit this to make an exception for one page e.g. mydomain.com/sitemap-news.xml - and keep this as http:// ?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As listed in comments here is how my entrie .htaccess looks

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^sitemap-news\.xml$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^sitemap-news\.xml$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an exception for sitemap file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^sitemap-news\.xml$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^sitemap-news\.xml$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi,

It's still not able to render the page, if I completely remove the .htaccess with the redirect code it works, but when adding my original code or your code, it's still creating an error on /sitemap-news.xml  (All other pages are working as intended)

Comment: You need to replace both of your existing rules with my code. Then try it out in a new browser to test `http://www.domain.com/sitemap-news.xml`

Comment: Hi,

I have tried this, the pages just loads a blank page with the http:// version now > Strange.

Comment: What URL did you open in your browser?

Comment: Hi - It's a wordpress powered site, so could be conflicts there, I don't want to publicise the url though unfortunately, so that won't help.

If you're sure you've supplied the right code, I'll run with it and see if I can work out the WP problem/conflict.

Comment: I was not asking your real domain. You can replace your domain with `domain.com` and then tell me what the URL is. Also if using WP make sure these rules are are just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Ah, sorry - ok.

mydomain.com/sitemap-news.xml
mydomain.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: ok so if you enter `http://domain.com/sitemap-news.xml` does it become `https://www.domain.com/sitemap-news.xml` ? Did you place this rule just below `RewriteBase` line?

Comment: Hi,

Let me edit my original post and I'll paste in my entire contents of .htacess - I can confirm that entering the http:// version doesn't redirect.

Comment: `entering the http:// version doesn't redirect`: Isn't that what you want for sitemap URL?

Comment: Ok, I've edited my original post.

That is the desired result, but no other pages redirect to https:// now either.

Comment: I provided your full .htaccess in my answer. Also make sure you have site and home URLs with `https://` in WP permalinks.

Comment: I can confirm that I have permalinks set to https:// - I'm on Litespeed server would that make a difference?

Comment: OK, I needed that extra bit in my WordPress, I've simply moved your code above this and it now works. - thanks very much for your help an patience with this.